# linq to sql Error : the required column does not exist

Tags: c#, iis, linq-to-sql

Sometimes when I visit my asp.net website see this error:

> The required column 'code' does not exist in the results.
>
> [InvalidOperationException: The required column 'code' does not exist
>   in the results.]
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderBase`1.GetColumnOrdinals(NamedColumn[]
>   namedColumns) +709670
>
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderBase`1..ctor(ObjectReaderSession`1
>   session, NamedColumn[] namedColumns, Object[] globals, Object[]
>   arguments, Int32 nLocals) +193
>
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderSession`1.CreateReader(Func`2
>   fnMaterialize, NamedColumn[] namedColumns, Object[] globals, Int32
>   nLocals, Boolean disposeDataReader) +113
>
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderFactory`2.Create(DbDataReader
>   dataReader, Boolean disposeDataReader, IReaderProvider provider,
>   Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[]
>   subQueries) +272
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query,
>   QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[]
>   parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object
>   lastResult) +2596
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query,
>   QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[]
>   userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries) +188
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression
>   query) +500    DAL.DataClassesDataContext.SP_Select_Agents(Nullable`1
>   code, Nullable`1 just_act) +182    BLL_Agency.LoadAgency(Int32 code,
>   Int32 actives) +62    BLL_Agency.LoadAgencyTable(Int32 code) +244
>   UserControl_Security_Login.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +221

and I think this error comes from a stored procedure that certainly has this column and runs correctly run in SQL Server Management Studio.

When I restart iis or replace `app_global.asax` problem will solve!

And after few days/hour problem will occur again.

Comment: We need to see the SQL and the calling Linq.  Otherwise there is **NO** way we can help

Comment: 99% of LINQ-to-SQL exceptions that occur after some period of time have to do with multiple threads accessing one context instance. If you use one global/singleton context you have to refactor that to context per request.

Comment: @Hogan Calling sp in server side is this: `code return System.Data.Linq.ISingleResult<DAL.sp_Select_AgencyUser_ByIDResult> LoadAgencyUserByID()' ` and dc is DataClassesDataContext that create in class constructor.

Comment: @GertArnold in this old web site never use thread in any where

Comment: So each user waits till the previous one is done? There are always threads in a web app. So what about the `DbContext`?

Comment: @GertArnold My means that never use any object of Thread class in user code(if i get your comment meaning),and object of dbcontext create in class constructor that call function with `code return System.Data.Linq.ISingleResult<DAL.sp_Select_AgencyUser_ByIDResult> LoadAgencyUserByID()`

Comment: This doesn't tell me anything about your context lifespans. One last try to get this clear: when and where do you create contexts and when are they disposed?

Comment: @GertArnold in login page load i do just this 
        `BLL_Agency MyAgency = new BLL_Agency();
        tab3_content.InnerHtml = MyAgency.LoadAgencyTable(-3);`
And this is Constructor of BLL_Agency `DataClassesDataContext dc;
 public BLL_Agency()
 {
        dc = new DataClassesDataContext();
 }` and LoadAgencyTable just call: `DAL.agency[] Agents = dc.SP_Select_Agents(code, actives);string temp="";for (int i = 0; i < Agents.Length; i++)
        {temp+=Agents[i].code;}` and some other code.but just in this line i use `code` column that show in asp.net exception.dc never dispose in any function.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is one case where we don't need to see the code.  It is possible you problem is caused because you never close your db connection.  If you never close your db connection that means you never open your db connection.  Sometimes database setups and network setups will close / timeout a connection if it is left open for to long.

To solve this kind of problem use the standard `using()` blocks around all your db code.  Then you will open a connection use it and close it again consistently.  .NET's connection pooling and caching does an excellent job of ensuring this type of use does not cause a performance penalty.

Comment: My Web site is old - nostandard code that inheritance to me! and for years havent any problem and never use `using()` in code.this error occur from about one month ago,and i never change this page that have this error!(this page is login page and when error occur any one can not login to site)

Comment: more backup to my idea... while the website has not changed the hardware of the hoster or the rules they impose might have -- maybe they put in a new switch with different keep - alive rules for example